# SSL key exchange encryption techniques

Tags: security, encryption, ssl, diffie-hellman

what are the differences between the three key exchange algortihms namely Anonymous DH, Ephermal DH and fixed DH?

Answer (score 9):

From [Cisco's docs](http://www.cisco.com/web/about/ac123/ac147/archived_issues/ipj_1-1/ssl.html):

> Fixed Diffie-Hellman: 
>   This a Diffie-Hellman key exchange in which
>   the server's certificate contains the
>   Diffie-Hellman public parameters
>   signed by the certificate authority
>   (CA). That is, the public-key
>   certificate contains the
>   Diffie-Hellman public-key parameters.
>   The client provides its Diffie-Hellman
>   public key parameters either in a
>   certificate, if client authentication
>   is required, or in a key exchange
>   message. This method results in a
>   fixed secret key between two peers,
>   based on the Diffie-Hellman
>   calculation using the fixed public
>   keys.
>
> Ephemeral Diffie-Hellman: 
>   This technique is used to create ephemeral
>   (temporary, one-time) secret keys. In
>   this case, the Diffie-Hellman public
>   keys are exchanged, and signed using
>   the sender's private RSA or DSS key.
>   The receiver can use the corresponding
>   public key to verify the signature.
>   Certificates are used to authenticate
>   the public keys. This option appears
>   to be the most secure of the three
>   Diffie-Hellman options because it
>   results in a temporary, authenticated
>   key.
>
> Anonymous Diffie-Hellman: 
>   The base Diffie-Hellman algorithm is used, with
>   no authentication. That is, each side
>   sends its public Diffie-Hellman
>   parameters to the other, with no
>   authentication. This approach is
>   vulnerable to man-in-the-middle
>   attacks, in which the attacker
>   conducts anonymous Diffie-Hellman
>   exchanges with both parties.