# Difference between EDH/DHE and DH

Tags: security, cryptography, key, diffie-hellman

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SSL key exchange encryption techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767125/ssl-key-exchange-encryption-techniques)

Some of the cipher suites of SSL/TLS are mentioned as DH and some as EDH.
Whats the difference between Ephemeral Diffie Hellman (EDH or DHE) and Diffie Hellman?

Comment: See my answer in the question referenced in the previous comment.